# Answer spamming

Tags: discussion, advertising, spam

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338004/jowierun) (jowierun, also [on superuser](https://superuser.com/users/39758/jowierun) and [a few places](http://www.google.com/#q=jowierun) [besides](http://au.linkedin.com/pub/paul-jowett/16/107/590)) is finding old questions related to document conversion and adding advertising for a document conversion product. Is this kind of promotion spam? Should they make their affiliation explicit? Should the 70-odd comments be deleted?

Comment: That is spam and will (should) be taken care of spam flags.

Comment: Good catch! ---

Comment: Can you post specific examples? Going through SO posts, I'm having a hard time finding them.

Comment: Have at it: http://www.google.com/#q=docmosis+jowierun+site%3Astackoverflow.com+|site%3Asuperuser.com  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729118/what-are-the-drawbacks-with-jasper-reports/2809362#2809362

Comment: @Tobu: What's spammy about that one, [2809362](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729118/what-are-the-drawbacks-with-jasper-reports/2809362#2809362)?  For a pretty vague and open-ended question, it looks like a decent answer; I'm upvoting it.

Comment: @Gnome It says “hi my friends didn't like that software, last I know they were looking at this better thing”. What it doesn't say is: I sell this, that one is my competitor, and the friends are actually clients.

Comment: @Tobu: He doesn't actually say "friends", which seems to make the difference for me here: omission vs misrepresentation.  However, you have omitted that he said "they" are using two different products now, which are *not* by the same company ("XML Publisher" is apparently [an Oracle product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_BI_Publisher)).

Comment: @Gnome Failure to provide relevant information *is* misrepresentation. Clients are people you know, and a product you sell is a product you use, but omitting the first half doesn't convey an accurate meaning.

Comment: @Tobu: Does he work for Oracle too (doesn't appear to be the case), or is his mention of that product just an inconvenient fact?  Is your omission of that also a misrepresentation, then?  If you actually read the answer, he says they are "looking into"; they may just be potential clients.  In that case, "one site I know of" seems a perfectly reasonable way to characterize them.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit of a weird one actually.  I've gone through the last 10 or so posts of his and the thing is, even though he keeps plugging the same products, he is *actually answering the questions.*

The answers all seem to be relevant and I haven't noticed any blatant copy/pasting.  And the products he keeps mentioning are all free or have free versions.  I agree that it *feels* very spammy, but should we start flagging answers en masse that might actually be useful?

Comment: There was such case earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library. Even though it was on topic, and answering the question, reviving every old question for that is in my opinion wrong.

Comment: Maybe invite him here to clarify?

Comment: @Gnoupi: I remember that, and I think it was somewhat different.  That user was providing no context for his answers - he was splashing copypasta everywhere.  If you read this particular user's answers carefully, you'll see that they are all written specifically to answer the question (not just "use this product", but explaining why and how).  It's definitely suspicious, but I'm not ready to call it *spam* yet.

Comment: @Down : [Invited](http://superuser.com/questions/19231/convert-office-document-to-pdf-with-horizontal-page-in-the-middle/151458#151458).

Comment: (P.S. I'm not specifically saying that we should definitely allow this - just that we should carefully consider the facts before flagging him into oblivion.)

Comment: His answers are relevant; but since he answers old questions, they are not helpful to the OP. The motivation might be 1. to get searchers to see the name of his product, which doesn't otherwise get mentioned on SO. 2. to publish positive opinions of the product on a high-ranking site.

Comment: @Tobu: Questions are supposed to stand the test of time.  Providing a relevant non-self-promotion answer on an old question seems to be okay.  The mere fact that this involves a product of his shouldn't change that.  Instead, factors like actually addressing the question (e.g. copypasta is good indication this is *not* happening) should be considered.

Comment: @Aaro, "copypasta," eh?  I'll have to remember that one.  +1.

Comment: @Aarobot: Agreed, he's plugging his product, but he openly discloses his relationship to it, plus he is writing a custom reply to each question with a fair degree of thoughtfulness, so I'd put this in the "advertising, but the good kind" category.

Comment: @Tobu: there's nothing wrong with adding a new answer to an old question; it's a good thing, if the answer is relevant and adds new information!

Comment: @Gnoupi very nicely put.

Comment: @Ether: I actually don't think he's disclosed his relationship, at least not on Stack Overflow.  It would help mitigate some of the spam complaints if he did, even if it's just in his profile.

Comment: @Aarobot: bingo. Reading an answer or two and then glancing at his profile might lead you to think that he's just recommending some 3rd-party product that he himself has used and liked. An answer like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021812/how-can-i-retrieve-the-amount-of-free-ram-from-a-java-program/3023335#3023335) merely borders on off-topic if there's no relationship between the author and the vendor... but it's most certainly spam if they're one and the same!

Comment: @Shog9: You're right, most of them seemed OK, but looking closer, there are a few that aren't really on topic.  Personally, I think this could be resolved by simply asking/requiring him to disclose his affiliation in his user profile, and flagging the spammiest posts (I'm still opposed to going on a flagging spree though).

Comment: @Shog9: JNIWrapper and Docmosis (the product he's accused of spamming) are apparently produced by entirely separate companies.  I only looked through websites and the info they made publicly available about their companies though; did I miss something?

Comment: @Gnome: I have no idea who makes the products he recommends, or if he's affiliated with any of them. That's my point: it's not clear from his posts, and it's not clear from his profile, so when you run across a recommendation that doesn't really belong it's easy to suspect an ulterior motive... Best-case scenario, he's just an (over-) enthusiastic user; worst-case, he's astroturfing and the ambiguity is quite intentional.

Comment: @Shog9: I've gone through several of his answers; it seems much more likely he's honestly answering about what he knows (i.e. what he does daily at his job) than has any ulterior motive (don't forget Occam), and we want that kind of person contributing to the site, right?  I addressed Tobu's lack of pointing to clear examples elsewhere.

Comment: @Gnome: I went through maybe a dozen answers, down-voted two and flagged one as spam. Two others weren't recommending *any* products (and were seemingly-decent, though I'm unfamiliar with the topics involved), and the rest appeared nominally on-topic.

Comment: @Shog9: I strongly believe we are all responsible for evaluating what we read (moreso online).  If there are no clear examples of spam and we can't tell the difference between an accused spammer and someone genuinely contributing, then, well, aren't they a positive member of our community?

Comment: @Gnome: I do agree that it's a good rule of thumb to evaluate these on a case-by-case basis, but when the vast majority of a user's answers *are* product recommendations it's worth keeping an eye on them: sad to say, ad agencies that hire people to play the role of "average user" while surreptitiously promoting their clients' products are hardly unheard of.

Comment: @Shog9: People paid to increase the overall value of SO by posting valid answers sounds like a great idea to me.  Let's get more of that.

Comment: @Gnome: if they stick to posting valid answers, I'm all for it. If they turn it into a wasteland of (semi-on-topic) product recommendations, I'm dead-set against it. Recommending a JNI library to someone who hasn't even made it clear that they *need to use JNI* isn't valuable, IMHO. [Recommending products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933448/apache-fop-org-apache-fop/2933579#2933579) to someone who has specifically [asked for help with a different product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706305/jasper-report-doc-export-margin-problem/2881920#2881920) is *at best* just noise.

Comment: @Shog9: So "no, you're going about this wrongly in some way, here are better alternatives" isn't a valid answer anymore? The first you link should probably be a comment instead (if it was, would you still consider it spam, or do you not consider it spam now, just a bad answer?), but there again, when he recommends what look like 2 competitors, it's hard to call it spam.

Comment: @Gnome, @Gnoupi: that SU question with the invite was deleted by community flags; i hope (but don't know) that he'll see it in his Recent Activities when he next logs in.

Comment: @Gnome: if someone goes around to a bunch of questions on parsing XML using regular expressions and recommends using an XML parser instead, it's a pretty safe bet they're just an enthusiastic user of XML parsers (or know something about the limitations of regular expressions...). If they go around recommending Xanadu-Milan LLC's parser (reasonable licensing terms, check it out!), then, sadly, there's reason to *suspect* something else at play. Note my emphasis: I'm not saying this guy is a spammer, because *I can't know that* - I'm just saying it's suspicious.

Comment: @Shog9: Ah, that may be a fundamental difference in how we're approaching this. I don't care about motivation when determining if something is spam.

Comment: @Gnome: but it's motivation that differentiates an enthusiastic user of a product from someone *pretending* to be an enthusiastic user in order to drum up interest in a product they've been paid to promote. The *other* common aspect of spam - the shear volume of "recommendations" - this guy already appears to be trying to hit.

Comment: @Shog9: Exactly, motivation is the only thing that differentiates them: what they actually post is identical, therefore we should treat them identically. Downvote bad answers, upvote good ones, etc.  Are we going to cast an evil eye at everyone that answers 3 or more questions a day in areas they know well, if those areas happen to be something related to what they do at their job every day? (Jon Skeet, you're next!)

Comment: @Gnome: I think that's a good strategy... We should treat this user the same way we treat users who answer, "Use jQuery" to every question on HTML/DOM manipulation: down-vote when unhelpful, flag when intrusive/annoying... and perhaps ban if it becomes a problem without any signs of ceasing. Really, what else *can* we do - we have no way of proving or disproving any kind of relationship with the products he's promoting, so taking preemptive measures stands a good chance at being an overreaction. Who knows? Maybe tomorrow he'll show up and post... code.

Comment: Wow, quite a discussion this sparked.  All I know for sure is, he submitted a few answers that were not very helpful, a few more that were actively annoying (spammy), and a fairly large number that were probably decent answers in spite of plugging a product.  Even if he *is* getting paid to promote, if he's actually *reading* the questions (not just doing a keyword search and posting blindly) and attempting to answer them in a meaningful way, that's OK in my book.  Although the answers he posted which *were* lousy/spammy, should definitely be downvoted/flagged.

Comment: Just to clarify: the guy does make a living of Docmosis. I tried to not name names, but linked to his LinkedIn profile. He works for Systemic Pty, the company behind Docmosis.

Comment: @Aarobot: He at least tried to answer helpfully ("he is actually answering the questions" as you said).  I suppose the real issue is the large distance in treatment of the barest mention of what you do for a living compared to [blatant idiocy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008475/what-is-the-ghost-design-pattern/3008508#3008508 "and there's far worse from this particular individual").  But I'll also be the first to flag as spam when they don't put any effort into answering questions – this is why I've asked Tobu for specific examples.

Comment: @Gnome: Sad that ASCII art can generate 20 upvotes anywhere other than Meta.  The inmates are truly running the asylum.

Answer (score 8):

In cases like these, I think the deciding factor is, are these messages being "posted indiscriminately?"

Like any other post, I think you have to **look at the content,** and not the user or their intentions. Many users are here for some form of self-promotion or another. Just because this user's area of expertise happens to be his product, that does not *necessarily* mean his content is spam.

As long as the user's posts are on-topic, helpful, and custom-written for the question being asked, I don't see that we have cause for complaint.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this seems more like an avid fan than a spammer (see various comments responding to specific instances mentioned).  Even the linkedin.com profile you found omits any relationship to the Docmosis project you think he's spamming.

And if we can't tell the difference between an avid fan who actually addresses the questions asked and someone involved in self-promotion... leaving them be is fine by me, even if they are "spamming".

If you can find better examples of spam, however, please include a list in your question; I'm sure plenty of people will evaluate them. I'm not defending him, but I am asking you to give concrete examples.

I have no problem with the *concept* of people answering using products they have developed or even help pay their bills.  In fact, I would encourage it – as long as those users actually respond to the questions asked and follow other conventions of the community.  We *want* experts on the site, and many of those are people who work with these things for a living.

Comment: I did not raise this issue to pick answers off one by one. The payroll relationship (Systemic write Docmosis) and intent to get publicity makes it advertising; the systematic pattern of behaviour, along with not mentioning the connection (come on, “avid fan?”), makes it spam.

Comment: Ah, I missed that they have a partnership (and I should have seen that).  Honest mistake.

Comment: @Tobu: We evaluate answers individually based on content, not authorship (at least, that is the goal).  *After* a pattern emerges is when you need to escalate.  If you don't want to point to specific examples, then please, don't raise the issue.